# Types for tailwind

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css

I am using `tailwind.config.js` in order to extend some colors:

```
const theme = {
  mode: 'jit',
  content: ['./index.html', './src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  darkMode: 'media', // 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {
       colors: {}
```

but then I might pass a color to a component in props in order to later use it as `border-${color}` and/or `text-${color}`.
Right now the value would be just of type `string` so I am not getting the tips, is there some way to get a type of the combined custom colors + default tailwind's colors ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [good way to use different class css in react case by case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71151572/good-way-to-use-different-class-css-in-react-case-by-case)

Comment: I think the question you linked is about (dynamic class names)[https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names], but I believe what OP is asking about is how to get typescript typings based on the existing theme/config. @EdLucas

Comment: @tevvek did you ever find a solution? I've got a similar situation that I'm looking for a solution for.

Answer (score -1):

You have to return the complete string `border-red-500` in place of `border-${color}`.

Like you can define a function like this

```
let {color} = props;
function getColor( color) {
  return 'border-" + color;
}
```

And then use it like this

```
<div className={`border-2 ${getColor}`}> hello world </div>
```

Comment: I think OP is wondering how to get it more strictly typed so that `color` can't just be any string. Instead I think OP is looking for a way to get the `color` prop to be typed strictly for the color values that exist in the theme.